# How to make wordpress theme option page in columns?

Tags: themes, twitter-bootstrap

I tried a lot with using bootstrap to show the WordPress theme options page to appear in grid view. As we do col-lg4 and so...

I added add_editor_style(); for bootstrap, nothing happened.

The only table works there. I just want to design the theme options page to look good for the admin by using the full space available as well as responsive.

If I want to use bootstrap, how to do that or any other better way for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a custom menu page for your theme options, then you can first use `add_menu_page()` to register the menu page. Then to use custom styles and scripts on that page, you need to enqueue them on `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.

Something along these lines,

```
function my_enqueue_admin_assets() {
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  // only enqueue assets on the custom page
  if ( empty( $screen->id ) || 'your_custom_menu_page_slug' !== $screen->id ) {
    return;
  }
  // wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src = false, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $media = 'all' );
  // wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src = false, $deps = array(), $ver = false, $in_footer = false );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_admin_assets' );
```

So enqueue the Bootstrap styles with the above code and then use the appropriate css classes on the markup you write for the `add_menu_page()` callback.